# Content Search Web Part really really slow

Tags: 2013, office-365

I'm working on Sharepoint 2013 (Office 365 version) and until last week everything was normal. But from today the Content Search Web Part (CSWP) seemed to have started to show some unexpected behaviours:

- When I add a CSWP to a page, I'm unable to edit it.
- When I try to get the Snippet code from either the Master Page Snippet page or Layour Snippet page the properties iframe never opens.

Below some screenshots:

When I select CSWP
[image: When I select CSWP]
When I select other web part (it works)
[image: When I select other web part]

Anyone come across with the same issue?
Could it have been caused by something I did? (I've only been uploading display templates, layouts and CSS files and they've all been loaded without errors, and also mapping some managed properties to crawlable properties)

**Edit: It seems to be working, although it takes approximately 10 minutes before anything appears on screen.**

Comment: Does the CSWP behave the same way if you put it in a site with the default masterpage and no css modifications?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. Just tried to be more patient, it seems it works but takes over 10 minutes before loading...

Comment: Try configuring your cswp by csom powershell. FYI: We have the same behavior in our environmemt and we have opened a case with microsoft and they are working on it.

Comment: How you tried stopping and starting the Distributed Cache Service? This sounds like the cache is not running, although it may appear to be started.

Comment: I think this must have been some Microsoft issue, since after Christmas it got back to a normal speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed by Microsoft, since now it's back to an acceptable speed and as far as I know, our admins didn't apply any fix/change to the site collection configurations.